# Previously I was able to remote into my azure virtual machine (windows server 2008r2) but now I get remote logins are currently disabled

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, remote-access, azure, remote-desktop-services

Up until today I was able to remote desktop into my windows server 2008 r2 virtual machine running in Azure and I was messing around with the settings for remote desktop session timeouts and now I get this message "remote logins are currently disabled" even when I try to login with an administrator account. I was thinking I could try the windwos 7 remote administration tools but I am unable to connect to machine using the public virtual ip address.

I am wondering what is the best route to take to re-enable remote logins from either command line, remote tools, or whatever.

Comment: What is the status of the VM in the Azure dashboard? If you restart/resize the VM does the problem still persist?

Comment: To answer your question, yes the problem still persisted after I restarted the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix my issue I had to create a new 2008 R2 VM. I also included both VMs in a virtual network so that the machines could see each other. Then I had to use the remote server management tools to connect up to the remote desktop services on the disabled server.

Under RD Session Host Configuration [image: Properties]

I had checked "Allow Connections, but prevent new logons" ... after setting it back to "allow all connections" I was able to remote into the machine again. So even though I had shut down the machine and restarted, that never cleared it up. Basically I was trying to limit one session per user, but the settings didn't work the way I thought it would. I guess I should have read up on Remote Desktop management before I did anything.

Comment: good to hear you figured it out.